# Why does Chromium not cache DNS for more than a minute?

Tags: dns, chrome, cache

I use Chromium and have problems with the DNS not being cached for the time that I would expect. Take the example.com domain. According to the DNS settings, this domain should be cached for another 26151 seconds:

```
$ dig example.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        26151   IN  A   93.184.216.34
```

However, when I open example.com in Chromium and I open chrome://net-internals/#dns then the IP is forgotten within a minute!

[image]

Why does Chromium not adhere to the TTL of the DNS setting of the domain? How can I force it to cache the DNS data until they expire?

Comment: _"... this domain should be cached for another 26151 seconds..."_ - No, the domain **may** be cached for 26151 seconds. DNS caching is not mandatory.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Chromium/Chrome does not cache DNS requests more than a minute indeed.

Interestingly enough, from [bugs-chromium - Issue 164026 - DNS TTL not honored from Apr 21 2011](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164026)

> The only DNS cache in the system is in chrome and it does not honor
> TTL.  We need to either fix chrome and/or add an intermediate cache
> that does handle TTL correctly.

Answer in the Dec 4 2012 ticket:

> The HostCache currently assumes TTL=60s for all positive results. With
> asynchronous DNS resolver, we plan to use TTL=max(60s,
> server_reported_ttl), i.e., at least 60s. The rationale is to improve
> the cache performance. (When a CDN NS provides TTL=10-20s, and it
> takes 30s+ to fetch all subresources, we often have to re-query for the same hostname during one page load.)

Ticket closed on Oct 10 2013 as:

> Chrome on CrOS uses asynchronous DNS resolver which honors TTL = max(60s, > server_reported_ttl)
>
> I'm closing this as WontFix (obsolete/works as intended).

This has been a known issue for years; their internal DNS resolver ignores the TTL of DNS records, and only caches DNS requests for 1 minute.

Users have been requesting for years, a feature to change that default behavior, and Google never created one.

In the past, you could disable the internal DNS resolver in `chrome://flags`, nowadays that functionally is not exposed anymore.

So summing it up, it is a feature, e.g. it does that by design.

(I initially wrote it could never be changed, which is not obviously not true. A really determined person can either recompile Chromium or hack Chrome binaries. ).

So, as an adenda: there is plenty of *documented* evidence Google engineers do not intend to respect the default TTL in received DNS answers in Chrome/ium.

From [Negative Caching of DNS Queries (DNS NCACHE)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308)

> As with caching positive responses it is sensible for a resolver to
> limit for how long it will cache a negative response...

While it is implied a resolver may/should impose a maximum limit on caching DNS answer, the 1-min limit on Google Chrome may be too low.

P.S. I actually discovered the answer for something that has been bugging me for years while retrieving Chrome stats to answer this question: [Chrome: DNS requests with random DNS names: malware?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363512/dns-requests-with-random-dns-names-malware)

PPS From the code bellow, it is apparent negative answers *are not cached* (TTL=0).

From https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/dns/host_resolver_impl.cc

```
  99 // Default TTL for successful resolutions with ProcTask.
 100 const unsigned kCacheEntryTTLSeconds = 60;
 101 
 102 // Default TTL for unsuccessful resolutions with ProcTask.
 103 const unsigned kNegativeCacheEntryTTLSeconds = 0;
 104 
 105 // Minimum TTL for successful resolutions with DnsTask.
 106 const unsigned kMinimumTTLSeconds = kCacheEntryTTLSeconds;
 
1518   // Called by ProcTask when it completes.
1519   void OnProcTaskComplete(base::TimeTicks start_time,
1520                           int net_error,
1521                           const AddressList& addr_list) {
1522     DCHECK(is_proc_running());
1523 
1524     if (dns_task_error_ != OK) {
1525       base::TimeDelta duration = base::TimeTicks::Now() - start_time;
1526       if (net_error == OK) {
1527         UMA_HISTOGRAM_LONG_TIMES_100("AsyncDNS.FallbackSuccess", duration);
1528         if ((dns_task_error_ == ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) &&
1529             ResemblesNetBIOSName(key_.hostname)) {
1530           UmaAsyncDnsResolveStatus(RESOLVE_STATUS_SUSPECT_NETBIOS);
1531         } else {
1532           UmaAsyncDnsResolveStatus(RESOLVE_STATUS_PROC_SUCCESS);
1533         }
1534         base::UmaHistogramSparse("Net.DNS.DnsTask.Errors",
1535                                  std::abs(dns_task_error_));
1536         resolver_->OnDnsTaskResolve(dns_task_error_);
1537       } else {
1538         UMA_HISTOGRAM_LONG_TIMES_100("AsyncDNS.FallbackFail", duration);
1539         UmaAsyncDnsResolveStatus(RESOLVE_STATUS_FAIL);
1540       }
1541     }
1542 
1543     if (ContainsIcannNameCollisionIp(addr_list))
1544       net_error = ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION;
1545 
1546     base::TimeDelta ttl =
                                              # always  0 seconds
1547         base::TimeDelta::FromSeconds(kNegativeCacheEntryTTLSeconds);
1548     if (net_error == OK)
                                              # always 60 seconds 
1549       ttl = base::TimeDelta::FromSeconds(kCacheEntryTTLSeconds);  
1550 
1551     // Source unknown because the system resolver could have gotten it from a
1552     // hosts file, its own cache, a DNS lookup or somewhere else.
1553     // Don't store the |ttl| in cache since it's not obtained from the server.
1554     CompleteRequests(
1555         MakeCacheEntry(net_error, addr_list, HostCache::Entry::SOURCE_UNKNOWN),
1556         ttl);
1557   }
```

Comment: Interestingly for me, chrome is caching DNS lookups based on the TTL for some domains, e.g. this domain `dougblack.io` so maybe the full rules are a bit more complicated. but 99 out of a hundred domains behave as you have described.

Comment: Chrome makes random-looking DNS requests to determine whether it's on a network that hijacks all DNS requests (like some paid wireless access points). Also, I imagine the "timeout" value you're looking at in the configuration is a 1-second timeout for DNS servers to respond, not a 1-minute TTL.

Comment: @duskwuff Yeah, in the other related answer I already talk about the hijacked DNS requests. I do agree it makes more sense the 1 second timeout, I erased that from the answer. Thanks. for remembering about paid wireless access points. I do know Apple does strange things to DNS to diagnose hijacked DNS requests, specially at wifi level, actually had no idea the Chrome resolver does it too; the point is that I saw many time that requests on the server side, and only today saw it in Chrome, and then there was light. No further comments about that...I am not surprised people already know that.

Comment: It's sad that chromium does a dns cache at all. Whenever I do quick changes on my NS and flush the dns cache I always have to keep in mind chrome does it by its own as well.

Comment: @OleK: Yeah, I had no idea Chrome even has its own DNS cache. Thanks to this page for pointing this out...

Comment: @OleK - I kinda agree, but at the same time I can see where a short... say, 60 seconds or so :) , cache is a good idea (to save a little network traffic) and still allows things like round robin dns, etc. to work

Comment: I'm a Googler and just left a comment on that bug to reopen it. But I've noticed that only 2 users before my had starred it in ~7 years, and I can't make much of a case. Can you please move the link to the bug to the top of your answer and make it more prominent?

Comment: @DanDascalescu Pretty interesting. Better now? If not enough, feel free to edit this answer. Actually as time goes by, Chrome is becoming the better browser...

Comment: @DanDascalescu See the source code I pasted and my PS2 comment.